# MP3 file not playing within a custom control

Tags: javascript, html, css, mp3

So there's this really cool button I want to use:

https://css-tricks.com/making-pure-css-playpause-button/

The 2 problems I'm having is I can't play the sound. I've put the mp3 file in the root directory so I'm assuming I need to put something like

```
<button class='button'>
  <sound src="play.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</button>
```

When I use the standard audio control it works fine but I really want to use this cool beans button. Also if I want to put text to the right of the button how would I do?

Also if I want to have a list of audio files how would that be achieved?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to post what you have tried and where you are struck, Stack overflow is meant for helping users fix their problems with help of community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put text to the right of the button you would put everything in another  with a display: flex; attribute and flex-direction: row;

For the audio, I create a new audio object in javascript. Then I can easily start and stop it from the code.

To use multiple sounds, we edit the toggleSound() function to use a string for the song name. Then we loop over the string to check if we have a sound associated with it. This is infinitely expandable. Just add more audio objects, and new cases in the switch statement and buttons to control them.

You can see that in each button we have to provide the audio name, so you can have multiple buttons per sound.

```js
// some example audio
const song1 = new Audio(
  "https://ia800905.us.archive.org/19/items/FREE_background_music_dhalius/backsound.mp3"
);

// some other audio
const song2 = new Audio(
  "https://ia800905.us.archive.org/19/items/FREE_background_music_dhalius/FormulaFantasy.mp3"
);

function toggleSound(audioName) {
  // switch for every case of the song name.
  switch(audioName.toString()) {
    case "song1":
      var x = song1;
      break;
    case "song2":
      var x = song2;
      break;
    default:
      // set default song
      var x = song1;
  }
  
  if (x.paused) {
    x.play();
  } else {
    x.pause();
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: lightgray;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
    <!-- your cool button div -->
    <div onclick="toggleSound('song1');" class="button">
      Song 1
    </div>
    Neat button for the first song.
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
    <!-- your cool button div -->
    <div onclick="toggleSound('song2');" class="button">
      Song 2
    </div>
    Button for the second song.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is excellent thanks so much! If I want to extend this by having a list of sounds, is there a way of writing arrays to make it easier? Instead of having to copy the code for each item? For example 
function toggleSound 1,2... 
.button 1,2...

Comment: Hello Brandon, I've edited my original answer to add a system that works. I've realized that you could also use an associative array to store the songs, but I didn't add that in the answer.

Comment: Have you seen the movie Snatch? You're Boris the blade! This is totally brilliant. Thanks so much Master Jedi Web Developer 

Comment: No problem! If you don't have any other questions, you can set the answer as correct, so others can use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html like this

```
<button onclick="play_pause()">play/pause</button>
<audio src="music.mp3" id="music"></audio>
```

And javascript like this

```
function play_pause(){

            if(document.getElementById("music").paused){ //check whether music is paused
            document.getElementById("music").play();     //if paused then play it
            }

            else{document.getElementById("music").pause();} //else pause it
        }
```